# Android Studio support v4

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I know this question was asked several times, but none of the answers helped me so far...

All I did was generating a preferences screen with Android Studio and now it tells me that NavUtils cannot be found. Even though my build.gradle looks right (I guess):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.brobox.getyourshitdone"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}
```

[image: Preference Activity]

I hope someone can help :/

**Edit:**
Just created a new project on my laptop and generated the SettingsActivity again. This is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.brobox.getyourshitdone"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
}
```

Still got the same error <.<

Comment: Did you try clean your project? (Build->Clean Project). And this line: `compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')` is not necessary.

Comment: Yup, did that several times!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well some time passed and now it works! I don't know what solved it exactly but I did the following:

- I updated to Android Studio 0.8.12 manually, because that was the only way to update it
- In a new project I tried to manually add a SettingsActivity and therefore added support-v4 to my repositories

Thanks for all your help on this silly question...

Answer (score 4):

You have to remove this line `implementation files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')` and you have to remove this file.

The support library should only be added by gradle. And you have done that in this line `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'`.

Your`targetSdkVersion` and your `compileSdkVersion` are also weird. Those values are not supported with the L developer preview.

`compileSdkversion`should be `'android-L'`, `targetSdkVersion` should be `'L'`.

Comment: Sorry but this does not work either. Why does this happen to me :/

Comment: Wolfram, I was wondering if you could help me with this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969590/what-is-the-expected-behavior-of-sqlite-crud-operations-after-a-configuration-ch) . It's not one of those "fix-this-for-me" questions, I promise.

Answer (score 1):

Press this button, and clean rebuild project.

And add to dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:+'
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yup, did that several times! But I'll try it again <.<

Comment: i test this 1 minute ago add dependencies

Comment: Nope, sorry. It seems to make it worse though
[link](http://i.imgur.com/rX2Xewt.png)