# What is the expected behavior of SQLite CRUD operations after a configuration change or if the activity that started those operations is destroyed?

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-background

I'm refactoring an app I made some time ago. Back then I was taking my first steps into Android and the easy way to go was to avoid orientation changes, for almost all my CRUD operations I used the `AsyncTask` class, didn't implement a Content Provider or used Fragments.

Now I have made some changes:

- I use `Fragment`s to encapsulate functionality
- All accesses to my database are done through a `Content Provider`
- I use `CursorLoader`s to retrieve my data taking advantage of the content      observation and automatic background loading the `LoaderFramework` brings.

The only problem I have now is that I'm not quite sure how to handle the rest of the CRUD operations (Create,Update, and Delete). 
I've found that I can use the `AsyncQueryHandler` class, but there's not enough information online.
One thing I like the Loader Framework, is that is aware of the Activity or Fragment lifecycle, but what about the `AsyncQueryHandler`?

- What happens to the operations that were started with `startDelete`, `startInsert`, `startUpdate` when the `Activity`/`Fragment` undergoes a configuration change? Or when I press the back button? Or worse yet, if the activity is destroyed?
- What is the expected behavior of this kind of operations in such cases? Should they be cancelled or should they continue to do their work?

All the operations I've mentioned above are not that complex. For real complex operations I've used `Service`s or `IntentService`s, but since I don't consider a good idea to run SQLite operations on the main thread I want to use a better solution, but first I need to know how that solution should react to the `Activity`/`Fragment` lifecycle events.

Any comments or suggestions would me greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you use **AsyncQueryHandler** you have to take into consideration that this abstract wrapper is created and executes provider operations on the thread that it was started on. If you call this from UI thread the callbacks will be sent to the UI thread. If you call this from another working thread, the callbacks will be sent to that working thread.

This is not bound to the lifecycle of the fragment or the activity, ContentProviders don't have an lifecycle.

The AsyncQueryHandler at an basic level, creates an Message object which is added to the MessageQueue of an single background thread. No matter from which activity/fragment you use the AsyncQueryHandler all the Message objects will end up on the same MessageQueue.
Once the background thread processes an request it will send the response back to the instance of the AsyncQueryHandler from which the request was initially made.

*My recommendation* is to use the **Loaders** from Android. These are directly tied to the lifecycle of the activity/fragment. You can have multiple Loaders in a LoaderManager(one LoaderManager per activity/fragment) which allows to do more complex operations. Your activity/fragment will automatically be notified when the content has changed(very useful when you want to combine it with your custom methods for CRUD operations or if you need to use long running services). Another very important feature they have is that they will always reconnect to the last Loader, thus you will avoid re-querying your content.

I recommend you search for some tutorials for implementing Loaders in Android. You can start with these:

- [Loaders - part 1](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html)
- [Loaders - part 2](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/understanding-loadermanager.html)
- [Loaders - part 3](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/implementing-loaders.html)
- [Loaders - part 4](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/09/tutorial-loader-loadermanager.html)

Answer for your last comments:

I suggest to use the EventBus library (https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to make the communication between your AsyncTasks/Thread and your other components.
You can start by creating an abstract AsyncTask/Thread and on top of that to make your specific command. 
For example:

```
public abstract class AbstractThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();

        command();
    }

    abstract void command();
}
```

In the abstract class you could make some DB initialization, verification or anything else that might make sense for your application.

```
public class InserTask extends AbstractThread{

    @Override
    void command() {
        //TODO: Add logic for the insert task
    }
}

public class UpdateTask extends AbstractThread{

    @Override
    void command() {
        //TODO: Add logic for the update task
    }
}
```

In these specific classes, just add your logic of the CRUD operation.

To have control over these threads, like when they should be stopped, paused, resumed you could create and ThreadPool manager which controls your threads. You can read more how to achieve this here: [Thread Pool](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/run-code.html)

Comment: lonut, thank you for taking the time to answer. I must confess that  I'm little bit confused. In your first paragraph you write "You will have to handle this kind of logic on other threads if you don't want to block the UI", but then you mention the background thread that all AsyncQueryHandler instances within an application add provider requests to. According to the book a read, AsyncQueryHandler always executes its operations on a background thread. The callbacks are, however, always called on the same thread that created the AsyncQueryHandler.

Comment: Now, the Loaders. I thought they were only intended to be used to "load" data. Anyway, about my other questions, what should I do when the activity that initiated the CRUD operations is paused or destroyed? Should those operations continue to do what they were doing, or should I try to cancel them? What is an app supposed to do in such cases?. Once again, thanks.

Comment: It depends on what do you want from your application. If you need them to keep going without your application use the Services, otherwise stick with the basic, Loaders, AsyncTasks, custom Threads. 
For even more control you can customize everything and use EventBus to make the communication between your components.

Comment: @lonut  If it was up to me, I'd use IntentServices for everything, but just imagine having to create a new class for every CRUD operation for each activity that uses my db. The same goes for AsyncTasks because if my memory serves me correctly if I wanted to handle configuration changes, I'd have to use retained fragments. Seriously, I wish google gave us clear guidance on what to do in these situations :'(

Comment: I know, they don't have everything set up in the Android system. But you can achieve what you want. You will have to create more classes, but not for each activity, make them generic and if you want add an extra layer on top of them to create explicit commands if you want to have some standard way to create CRUD operations. I would use custom Threads and control my own Pool as it will give me more control over the operations that run.

Comment: @lonut Do you think you could tell me a little more about this part "if you want add an extra layer on top of them to create EXPLICIT COMMANDS if you want to have some standard way to create CRUD operations"? I was thinking about creating an reusable AsyncTask and the only thing that came to mind was to use interfaces and a switch to decide which operation to excute.